# React Native setState is not consistant

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here my state is not updated after using setState.log shows default value most of the time. Why is `setState` not consistent?

```
export default class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // icons to listview (arrow icon)
    this.icons = {
      up: require("../../assets/ic_play_circle_down.png"),
      down: require("../../assets/ic_play_circle_up.png")
    };

    this.state = {
      title: props.title,
      // getting screen size (width and height)
      let: ({ width, height } = Dimensions.get("window")),

      // collapsed check the listview expanded or not if it is true: list view not expanded
      collapsed: true,

      isApproved: false,
      comment: "dummy comment"
    };
  }
  acceptApproval = () => {
    this.setState({ isApproved: true });
    console.log("Approved TICK " + this.state.isApproved);
    this.verifyApprovals();
  };

  regectApproval = () => {
    this.setState({ isApproved: false });
    console.log("Approved" + this.state.isApproved);
    this.verifyApprovals();
  };
```

Comment: because setState is async.

Comment: So how can I solve that ?

Comment: here you can learn about `setState`: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know `setState` is asynchronously, You should invoke your second function as a callback to setState

```
this.setState({ isApproved: true }, function(){
   this._setApproval(true)
  });

  };
_setApproval(){
console.log("Approved TICK " + this.state.isApproved);
    this.verifyApprovals();
}

  regectApproval = () => {
    this.setState({ isApproved: false } , function() {
    this._setRejection();
});

  };

_setRejection() {
console.log("Approved" + this.state.isApproved);
    this.verifyApprovals();
}
```

Comment: I solved my issue.I did not know about "setState -> asynchronous"

Comment: okay..can u please put the code that is working here @HRCJ

Comment: acceptApproval = () => {
    this.setState(
      { isApproved: true, collapsed: !this.state.collapsed },
      function() {
        this.verifyApprovals();
      }
    );
  };